# Motherboard does not recognize PCI express card (Win7)

Tags: motherboard, sata, pci-express, nvme

I have a Gigabyte GA-990fxa-ud3e main board (9 years old, still running strong). I just got a free NVME drive (Toshiba KXG50ZNV256G). The mobo has no support for NVME, so I purchased two different [adapters](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Sabrent-NVMe-Aluminium-Heatsink-EC-PCIE/dp/B084GDY2PW/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_pb_opt?ie=UTF8&th=1) from Amazon. None of them is recognized. They appear in Device manager under "other devices" but with an yellow icon/warning, with the message "The drivers for this device are not installed (Code 28)".
[image]

Do I need to turn something on in BIOS?
The seller says I need no drivers (Win 7 64bit) for this device.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by installing "Microsoft Hotfix for Installing Windows 7 on NVMe" aka "Windows6.1-KB2990941-x64" from [here](https://support.lenovo.com/de/en/downloads/ds121505-microsoft-hotfix-for-installing-windows-7-on-nvme-thinkcentre).
Some related discussions [here](https://www.win-raid.com/t3452f46-Toshiba-XG-NVMe-Drivers-for-Installing-Windows.html) (really technical/dense).